# PHP syntax errors around echo HTML tags

Tags: php

I'm struggling to understand these errors in my PHP code when I try to use the 'echo' command. My code is supposed to output a HTML page with various variables that change the results of links and other strings.

1) 'echo “”;'
syntax error, unexpected '>' (Line 95)

$cimg is a variable that I'm just appending to a URL with ?cimg as an argument.

2) In an if then else, I have the following lines as things to occur (be printed in the webpage) if certain conditions are true.

```
echo ‘Please visit Homepage.com and try again.’;
```

syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' (Line 146)

```
echo ‘Please visit Homepage.com and try again - the product is not long enough.’;
```

syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' (Line 162)

3) Some bizarre error here as well...

```
echo ‘<li><li><a href="#uk"><img src="UK128.png" style="width:16px;height:16px"> UK</a><a href="#us"><img src="US128.png"  style="width:16px;height:16px"> US</a></li> <li><a href="#ca"><img src="CA128.png" style="width:16px;height:16px"> Canada</a></li>‘;
```

Gives me syntax error, unexpected '>' (Line 211)

4)  `echo '<div id="uk">';
echo '<div id="us">';`

Gives me syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' (Line 230)

5)  `echo  '</div>';`

Gives me syntax error, unexpected '/' (Line 233)

6)  `echo'<img src="US128.png" style="width:16px;height:16px"> US</a></li> <li><a href="#uk"><img src="UK128.png" style="width:16px;height:16px"> UK</a></li>’;`

syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE (Line 217). Say what?

7) `echo  “$AUKurl”;`

syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' (Line 228)

$AUKurl is a string variable that is calculated earlier. I just want to display it as an output here.

These errors are from various online PHP error testers that I'm testing my code in. MS VS Code Editor also gives similar errors. Am I messing up on how to use echo?

8) If I just take these problematic lines, collate them, and stick them in PHPTester.net (if anyone wants to try it, here's the code block) I get a Expectation Failed. I don't think I'm trying to do anything difficult here - just outputing basic HTML and squeezing the odd variable in?

```
<?php

$cimg=123456
$AUKurl=123456

echo “<center><a href=?cimg='.$cimg.'><img src=$cimg.png></img></a></center>”;'
echo ‘Please visit Homepage.com and try again.’; 
echo ‘Please visit Homepage.com and try again - the product is not long enough.’;/
echo ‘<li><li><a href="#uk"><img src="UK128.png" style="width:16px;height:16px"> UK</a><a href="#us"><img src="US128.png"  style="width:16px;height:16px"> US</a></li> <li><a href="#ca"><img src="CA128.png" style="width:16px;height:16px"> Canada</a></li>‘; 
echo '<div id="uk">';
echo '<div id="us">';` 
echo  '</div>';` 
echo'<img src="US128.png" style="width:16px;height:16px"> US</a></li> <li><a href="#uk"><img src="UK128.png" style="width:16px;height:16px"> UK</a></li>’;` 
echo  “$AUKurl”;`
    ?>
```

Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: Most of your errors are due to the invalid `inverted comma` characters. Use `'` or `"` only, not `‘` or `“`.

Comment: Where do these wonky  `‘ ’` quotes come from?

Comment: The stylized quotes you're using are ongoing evidence of the classic mistake that *a word processor is not an IDE*.

Comment: Thank you all. Ooops, I used Google Docs to initially write my code as I liked highlighting and commenting on the side before I transferred to an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP strings need to be quoted using one of two characters:

- U+0027 : APOSTROPHE {APL quote}
- U+0022 : QUOTATION MARK

The latter of which allows variable interpolation.

You are using a strange mix of:

- U+2018 : LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK {single turned comma quotation mark}
- U+2019 : RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK {single comma quotation mark}
- U+201C : LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK {double turned comma quotation mark}
- U+201D : RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK {double comma quotation mark}

This is typically caused by trying to write code using a tool that is not designed for it such as Microsoft Word or the output of the Wordpress page editor.

Use a text editor such as Visual Studio Code instead.

Comment: Ah! Thank you all. I made the mistake of initially writing my code in Google Docs, before copying it over to MS Visual Studio Code. I know, very silly... :)